# About google OR Tools (python)

Tags: python, or-tools

I'm trying to express this constraint through google linear solver

> (CBC_MIXED_INTEGER)PROGRAMMING)

Implementing this equation

[image: Implementing this equation]

written as the following code:

```
for i in range(data['I']):
    for j in range(data['J1']):
        constraint1 = [t[i][j]*y[(i, j)]]
        solver.Add(25*x[i]>=constraint1[0])
```

However, it does not work at all

**EDIT:** To provide more information:

That equation stands for:

1. x[i]= a facility in region i (Boolean variable)
2. y[(i,j)]= when the facility at region i provide products to region j (Boolean variable)
3. t[i][j]=distance between region i and j
4. +(J1=is the Set of regions which is subset of J)

Therefore, that equation stands for:

'Only if when the region j is closer than 25, it gets chance to receive products from the facility located at region i'

However, when I add that constraint, the result show that all the x[i]=0 and all the y[i][j] when j belongs to J1.

Can you please help me?

I'm adding all the code to help you understand better.

data are just parameters like distance and price

```py
def create_data_model():
    data = {}   
    #obj_coeffs
    data['obj_coeffs'] = objcoeff
    data['I']=226
    data['J']=226
    data['J1']=106
    data['J2']=226
    data['coeff_t']=t
    data['coeff_a']=a
    data['coeff_r']=r
    data['coeff_d']=d
    data['coeff_cov']=cov

    return data


from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp


def main():

        solver = pywraplp.Solver('onedaydelivery',
                                pywraplp.Solver.CBC_MIXED_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING)

        infinity = solver.infinity()

        #*********************************decision variables -*********************************


        x = {}
        for i in range(data['I']):
            x[i] = solver.BoolVar('x[%i]' % i)

        y = {}
        for i in range(data['I']):
            for j in range(data['J']):
                y[(i,j)] = solver.BoolVar('y[%i][%i]' % (i,j))

        z = {}
        for i in range(data['I']):
            z[i] = solver.IntVar(0, infinity, 'z[%i]' % i)

        #**********************************objective function**********************************

        obj_expr = [data['obj_coeffs'][i][0]*data['obj_coeffs'][j][1] * y[(i,j)]
                    -data['obj_coeffs'][i][2]*data['obj_coeffs'][j][3] * y[(i,j)]
                    -data['obj_coeffs'][i][4]*data['obj_coeffs'][j][5] * y[(i,j)]
                    -data['obj_coeffs'][i][6]* x[i]
                    -data['obj_coeffs'][j][7]*y[(i,j)]*data['obj_coeffs'][i][8]
                    *data['obj_coeffs'][i][9]*data['obj_coeffs'][i][10]*data['obj_coeffs'][i][11]
                    -(z[i]/data['obj_coeffs'][i][12]*data['obj_coeffs'][i][13])
                    for i in range(data['I']) for j in range(data['J'])]
        solver.Maximize(solver.Sum(obj_expr))

        #**********************************constraints**********************************
        #**********************************constraint #1***********************************

        for i in range(data['I']):
            for j in range(data['J1']):
                constraint1 = [t[i][j]*y[(i,j)]-25*x[i]]
                solver.Add(constraint1[0]<=0)


        #**********************************constraint #2***********************************

        for i in range(data['I']):
            for j in range(data['J1'],data['J2']):
                constraint2 = [t[i][j]*y[(i,j)]-50*x[i]]
                solver.Add(constraint2[0]<=0)

        #**********************************constraint #3***********************************

        for j in range(data['J']):
            constraint3 = [y[(i,j)] for i in range(data['I'])]
            cs3=solver.Sum(constraint3)
            solver.Add(cs3 <= 1)

        #**********************************constraint #4***********************************

        for i in range(data['I']):
            constraint4 = [a[j][0]*y[(i,j)] for j in range(data['J'])]
            cs4=solver.Sum(constraint4)
            solver.Add(z[i]>=cs4)

        #**********************************execution************************************

        status = solver.Solve()

        if status == pywraplp.Solver.OPTIMAL:
            print('Objective value =', solver.Objective().Value())

            for i in range(data['I']):
                print(x[i].name(), ' = ', x[i].solution_value())

            for i in range(data['I']):
                for j in range(data['J']):
                    print(y[(i,j)].name(), ' = ', y[(i,j)].solution_value())

            for i in range(data['I']):
                print(z[i].name(), ' = ', z[i].solution_value())

            for i in range(data['I']):
                for j in range(data['J']):
                    if (y[(i,j)].solution_value())==1:
                        print(y[(i,j)].name(), ' = ', y[(i,j)].solution_value())

            print()
            print('Problem solved in %f milliseconds' % solver.wall_time())
            print('Problem solved in %d iterations' % solver.iterations())
            print('Problem solved in %d branch-and-bound nodes' % solver.nodes())
        else:
            print('The problem does not have an optimal solution.')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When constraint 3 and 4 are applied (except 1 and 2), it shows same result as CPLEX

However, when constraint 1 and 2 are also applied, all the value (x,y,z) become 0.

Comment: What is not working? Are you not getting expected results or is there any exception?
Can you please add the code instead of pasting the image?

Comment: I added more information. Thank you

Comment: I do not trust CBC.

Comment: Then, which solver do you prefer? (the open source one)

Comment: You mean that its not the problem of writing the constraint, but the problem of solver?

Comment: @SIK  welcome to stackoverflow. I tried to correct your code because it obviously lacked imports. I also edited it for ease of reading, because the description has several elements. I think maybe you can reduce the code in order to isolate the problem you want answered, please be mindful of the guidelines to posting a minimum reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @SIK I was going to try and answer this question, but I don't see where your `data['I']` dictionary is defined. It would be convenient to include a minimalist example of your `data['I']`defined in the code, so users wanting to help can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you I just added the information about it